# Sharing a directory tree problem from windows to android es explorer

Tags: windows, file-management, file-permissions, file-sharing

There are several child folders in parent folder on windows 8.

Times ago I shared some child folders and accessed them from android es explorer without problems. Then I removed all child folders shares and instead shared their parent folder.

During the parent folder sharing the window appeared listing some of the previous child shares and asking "some of the folders were previously shared. you can replace their current settings with the same setting you just applied to the folder you shared".

If I click change settings after processing for a while it ends up with "folder can not be shared". Despite the message it is shared but access to those children is forbidden, they are not visible.

Comment: Where do you get that message: on your Windows machine, or in ES File Explorer?

Comment: windows while sharing

Comment: I re-clicked every child manually from explorer to stop sharing just to make sure. now just one child gets problem to be shared. I share parent and it fails to be shared

Comment: Just disconnect your tablet completely from WiFi while editing the shares (you probably cannot modify a share that is in use). If the problems still persist, here is the wrong place to ask, as that's rather a Windows issue then (check [SU] or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) instead then – but make sure to read their help pages where it's best fitting, and don't cross-post on both ;)).